# Pandas DataFrame - How to handle column names which can change spelling/name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am building a process to ingest a file which can occasionally have a different name for the same column. For instance:

```
zipcode, zip, zipcodes, property_zipcode
```

Safe to assume at least `zip` needs to always be in the name. If not, the script can exit and thats acceptable. The idea is to perform any data transformations using the pandas dataframe, and specifically grouping data by the column named something like zipcodes.

Code sample below. The df_reported could be any df with address/zipcode combinations. But for now its basically an excel file turned to df via read_excel.

```
def add_adressid_to_df(df_reported):
"""map pandas DataFrame of addresses and zipcodes to address_ids"""
assert isinstance(df_reported, pd.DataFrame)
if not df_reported.empty:
    # remove spaces and case
    df_reported.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
    df_reported.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
    df_reported.columns = df_reported.columns.str.replace(r' ', '')
    df_reported.columns = map(str.lower, df_reported.columns)

    if 'zipcode' and 'address' in df_reported.columns:
        df_reported.address = df_reported.address.astype(str)
        df_reported.zipcode = df_reported.zipcode.astype(int)
        logging.info('Looking up address_ids for self-reported...')
        df_reported['address_id'] = df_reported.apply(lambda id: find_address_id(id['address'], id['zipcode']), axis=1)
    else:
        logging.error('Missing either address or zip[code] column.')
        return None
return df_reported
```

Comment: Please add your code sample that you have tried so far to achieve this

Comment: Depends how modular you want your code and how much you want to be able to unit test it. You could write a function `def infer_zip_col(list_of_cols)` that takes the possible column names and returns the one that, based on your rules, should be considered the zip code col. Then the rest of your current function could work with the variable `zip_col` as opposed to hard-coding the particular string. But that could be difficult to fully protect against all weird edge cases. More manually you could add `zip_col` as an argument you manually specify to your process.

Comment: @Sabil - edits above. I need to clean it up, I know its kinda crap right now.

Answer (score 0):

If the file header is always the same, you can ignore the header and hardcode a specific header using the `names` parameter to overwrite the column names.

Another way is to accept all columns and pass a function to `pandas.DataFrame.rename` to rename all fields containing "zip" as such:

```
df.rename(columns = lambda col: 'zip' if 'zip' in col else col)
```

Obviously, if you have highly variant data headers, this could be dangerous if there is a possibility for multiple columns to contain the "zip" substring.